# How to define / reset all object items to zero

Tags: javascript

I need to initiate an object like I am below. Is there an easier way to initialise it and periodically resetting it so all values are 0, Or is it just the case of using a for loop?

```
var vote_tally = {};
vote_tally[1]=0;
vote_tally[2]=0;
vote_tally[3]=0;
vote_tally[4]=0;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you might want to be using an array and not an object here...

Comment: But yes, you can just loop.  `Object.forEach` or even a simple `for` loop can do this.

Comment: I program in Javascript since 2009 and I never saw any way to do it without a loop...

Comment: Initialize the object in a function and call the function again when you need to reset it.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to do this with an object or an array? With an object, if you're assigning a value by passing a Number to an object in bracket notation, you're actually just creating a string version of that number as a key.

Comment: I need an associative array. Even though for now it is just numbers.

Comment: @Somk There is no such thing as an associative array in JavaScript. Please explain what you are trying to do instead.

Comment: I know that is why I am doing it via an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by providing a constructor function and adding to its prototype.

```
function MyObject(value) {
    value = value || 0;
    this[1] = value;
    this[2] = value;
    this[3] = value;
    this[4] = value;
}

MyObject.prototype.reset = function (value) {
    value = value || 0;
    for (var key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            this[key] = value;
        }
    }
};

var o = new MyObject();
o['1'] = 42;
o.reset();
console.log();
// {1:0,2:0,3:0}
```

If you want to make an array of arbitrary length and initialize all values to 0. One can do this.

```
function initArray(size, value) {
    value = value || 0;
    return Array.apply(0, Array(size)).map(function() {return value;});
}

var a = initArray(10);
console.log(a);
// [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

var b = initArray(10, 1);
console.log(b);
// [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

If you want to reset all values of the array, One can do this. However it is not good practice to modify JavaScript built-in prototypes.

```
Array.prototype._reset = function (value) {
    value = value || 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i += 1) {
        this[i] = value;
    }
};

b._reset();
console.log(b);
// [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can instantiate an array like this:

```
var array = [0, 0, 0];
```

Object:

```
var object = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};
```

To empty it you can just write: `array = []`

But please explain what it is that you are trying to do since you might be approaching this from the wrong angle.